# Data from sql database is not rendering on EJS page unless it is in a loop (using node, express, ejs, mysql)

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, ejs

================ROUTE=============

```
app.get("/forums/:id", function(req, res){

connection.query('SELECT * FROM Forums where ForumID = ?', [req.params.id], function (err, forumResults) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(forumResults);

    connection.query('SELECT * FROM  Users_Comments_Topics_Forums where ForumID = ?',[req.params.id], function (err, topicResults) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(topicResults);

             res.render("Forums/show", {topic: topicResults, forum: forumResults});
});
});
});
```

Note: When the page loads, it shows me the results through the console.log so I know the data passed through. I don't believe that the issue lies within the route for that reason but I could be wrong.
===================EJS Page================

This Part works perfectly. The data from the database renders on the page here.

```
   <%forum.forEach(function(forum){%>
            <div class="container card">

                <div class="container">
                    <div class="container forum_square">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-6 block">
                                <a href ="/forums/<%= forum.ForumID %>"> <h5><%=forum.Board %></h5></a>  
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                               <p><%= forum.Description %></p>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <% }); %>

                    </div>
```

However, just below...

```
<div class="col-lg-6 card description">


                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Welcome to <%=forum.Board%></h5>
                    <p class="card-text"><%=forum.Board %></p>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="forums/new" role="button">Make new Forum</a>


            </div>
        </div>
```

forum.Board does not show up on the page. In addition to that, even if you erase everything else on the page and just type <%=forum.Board%>, it will not show up. So far it only shows up in when within a loop.

==================WHAT I'VE TRIED========================

I have tried adding and removing spaces between the template tags and the data

I have tried using <%- instead of <%=

I've tried to roll back to a previous build where it worked perfectly for me before.

Does anyone know what could be going on?

Comment: can you try with <%=  String(forum.Board) %>. I guess forum.Board is not in primitive type.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. It shows up as "undefined" instead of just a blank.

Answer (score 0):

The variable forum you pass to the ejs page is an array.
In the foreach you use the same name for the entity inside:

```
  <%forum.forEach(function(forum){%>
```

Outside the foreach the variable forum, which is an array, does not have a property Board.

You can try to write the first element:

```
<% if (forum.length > 0) { %>
 <h5 class="card-title">Welcome to <%=forum[0].Board%></h5>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't working either. "Cannot read property '0' of undefined".is what I get when I do that. It's like it just doesn't see it at all

Comment: But is it in the same ejs page of the running example ? In the second line of my code "forum" can't be undefined: the error would arise in the "if" code and the error should be "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Comment: Yes it's in the same ejs page. Here is a screenshot https://imgur.com/a/ZCkt2FH

Comment: The error is in a subsequent line, where you write `forum.Board[0]` , in a previous line you correctly wrote `<%=forum[0].Board%>`

Comment: The images are identical, the error is in line 41 of the file show.ejs: where you use form.Board[0]. You must use form[0].Board.

Comment: The images are not identical. I made the edit you suggested and took a screenshot of the resulting error.

Comment: Effectively the images are not identical, but the code they show is the same. And the error is the same, in the same line of the same file: line 41 of show.ejs, where you write `forum.Board[0]` that is not correct. Sorry to not be helpfull. Bye